# Como pasar una matriz de tamaño dinamico por argumento a otra funcion

Tags: c++

estoy haciendo una funcion que suma los elementos de la columna de una matriz, el problema es que en un menu ingreso la matriz y luego tengo que llamar a la funcion, así :

```
void matrix(){
    char** opciones = new char*[4];
    opciones[0] = "Sumar dos matrices";
    opciones[1] = "Multiplicar dos matrices";
    opciones[2] = "Sumar columna";
    opciones[3] = "Sumar fila";
    int opc;
    int f1;
    int c1;
    cout<<"Ingrese las filas de la matriz 1: ";
    cin>>f1;
    cout<<"Ingrese las columnas de la matriz 1: ";
    cin>>c1;
    int matrix1[f1][c1];
    for(int i=0;i<f1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<c1;j++){
            cout<<"["<<i+1<<"],["<<j+1<<"] => ";
            cin>>matrix1[i][j];
        };
    };


    do{
        opc = menu(opciones, 4);
        switch( opc ){
            case 1: sumatrix(); break;
            case 2: multimatrix(matrix1); break;
            case 3: sumacolumna(); break;
            case 4: sumafila(); break;
        };
    }while(opc!=0);
};
```

En la parte de la opcion case 1, se supone deberia pasar el argumento asi:

```
case 1: sumatrix(matrix1); break;
```

Y en la funcion recibir el argumento asi:

```
    int** sumatrix(int** matrix1){
};
```

Pero me da varios errores y no me deja trabajar con esta, como hago, y tambien para pasar los valores f1 y c1 que los voy a necesitar dentro de la funcion

La matriz es de tamaño dinamico.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, pásate por el [tour] y [ask] para saber cómo presentar una pregunta correctamente (y para ganar tu primera medalla). En resumen, es preferible que presentes un ejemplo **mínimo** y **completo** que reproduzca el problema para entender correctamente tu caso y darte una respuesta adecuada... con las dos líneas de ejemplo que pones es complicado saber qué te está fallando exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

En C y en C++ las formaciones<sup>1</sup> son convertibles implícitamente a punteros, el nombre de la formación será el puntero al primer elemento de la misma.

Así pues el nombre una formación de una dimensión tendrá como tipo "*puntero al dato almacenado en la formación*". En el caso de formaciones de dos dimensiones el tipo será doble puntero, es decir: "*puntero a puntero al dato almacenado en la formación*".

Si tu función `sumatrix` tiene esta firma:

```
int** sumatrix(int**)
```

Entonces tu variable `matrix1`, que es una formación de dos dimensiones, puede ser pasada a dicha función pues su nombre es un puntero a puntero a `int`.

#### Las formaciones requieren un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación.

Estás declarando `matrix1` con dos tamaños que son recogidos en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int f1;
int c1;
cout<<"Ingrese las filas de la matriz 1: ";
cin>>f1;
cout<<"Ingrese las columnas de la matriz 1: ";
cin>>c1;
int matrix1[f1][c1];
```

Esto está prohibido en C y en C++ (¿tal vez son esos los errores que recibes?), si tu compilador lo acepta será por disponer de una extensión que hace que este código sea legal, pero no sería código estándar al ser una extensión de compilador y en consecuencia podría no funcionar en otros compiladores, no tener un comportamiento homogéneo en otros compiladores o dejar de funcionar en otra versión de tu mismo compilador. Lee [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) para más información.

#### C++ no dispone de un mecanismo para crear formaciones 2D con memoria dinámica.

No es posible pedir una formación de dos dimensiones con memoria dinámica (`new`) y tu formación de dos dimensiones necesita alojarse en memoria dinámica porque su tamaño sólo es conocido en tiempo de ejecución, así que tu única opción es la siguiente:

```
int f1;
int c1;
cout<<"Ingrese las filas de la matriz 1: ";
cin>>f1;
cout<<"Ingrese las columnas de la matriz 1: ";
cin>>c1;
int *matrix1 = new int[f1 * c1];
```

Ésta es la manera correcta de crear una formación cuyo tamaño es conocido en tiempo de ejecución. Para obtener el elemento de la fila `y` y columna `x` deberíamos calcular su posición de la siguiente manera:

> Índice del elemento = (y * lado) + x

Una función auxiliar puede ser útil:

```
int &elemento(int *&matrix, int ancho, int x, int y) {
    return matrix[(y * ancho) + x];
}
```

Entonces, todas las funciones que vayan a tratar con tus formaciones bidimensionales deberían recibir como parámetro el ancho (y según el caso también el alto) de la formación bidimensional.

---

1. También conocidas como "arreglos", o en inglés "arrays".